# fadeIn and fadeOut not working for image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I want to display particular image(among them) on the side when I do mouseover on certain coordinates on image2. Using `document.getElementById("xyz1").style.display="block"` works but not `document.getElementById("xyz1").fadeIn()`. Any ideas how to cause fadeIn and fadeOut effects?

What I wanna do is that when I mouseover on image1, image0 should fadeOut and image1 should fadeIn and then when I mouseover on image0, image1 should fadeOut and image0 should fadeIn

HTML:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="1,1,40,40" onmouseover ="f(0)">
<area shape="rect" coords="50,50,100,100" onmouseover ="f(1)">

<img id="image0"  src="../img1.jpg" style="display:block">
<img id="image1"  src="../img2.jpg" style="display:none">
```

JS:
Version that works:

```
function f(i){
  document.getElementById("image0").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("image1").style.display="none";
```

JS:
Version that does not work(nothing happens, no change):

```
function f(i){
  document.getElementById("image0").fadeIn();
  document.getElementById("image1").fadeOut;
```

Comment: `fadeIn()` is a jquery method not pure JS method. You have to put your DOM element into `$()` before being able to use `fadeIn()`.

Comment: Just a quick note: when you are trying to figure out a problem in javascript always check the developer console for errors. In this case it probably would have displayed a useful message like `undefined is not a function` then you will have a clue to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are jQuery methods (not native JavaScript methods). If you reference the latest [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/), you can turn your elements into jQuery objects and then apply your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

```
$('#image0').fadeIn();
$('#image1').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fadeIn() and fadeOut() exists only in jQuery

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use these functions instead of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```
function infnc(){$('img').animate({opacity:'0'},300);}
function outfnc(){$('img').animate({opacity:'1'},300);}
```

Comment: fadeIn works it's just that the OP is not using it properly